# Repeat bash command for n seconds

Tags: bash

I've seen a lot of methods to repeat a bash command once every n seconds, but none to repeat a command *for* n seconds.

Is there a way to repeat a command for n seconds? So if my command takes one second to execute, it'll run ten times. If it takes two seconds, it'll run five times.

If it takes seven seconds, it would execute two times (and no more), or perhaps it would exit the script.

Right now I'm doing it by looking at the amount of time it takes for my script to execute once, and then calculating how many times I need to repeat it for it to execute for n seconds. However, this is slightly unreliable as I've found that the time required to run the script deviates a bit.

Comment: For what sort of command is it *useful* to execute an unknown number of times during a fixed interval? If the job is currently executing when your interval expires, do you want to kill the job, or just not start a new instance once that one completes?

Comment: Right now I just want to blink my keyboard for a specific number of seconds. I don't really mind how many times it blinks

Comment: I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow. If my downvoter could please explain to my why he or she downvoted, I'd happily emend any errors I made (and this will likely help me avoid related errors in the future)

Comment: You might look at [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
timetorun=30    # In seconds
stoptime=$((timetorun + $(date +%s)))
while [ $(date +%s) -lt $stoptime ]; do
    something
done
```

Note that this will keep running the command until `timetorun` seconds have passed, so generally it'll actually run longer than that. For an extreme example, if `timetorun` is 30 seconds and the program takes 29 seconds, it'll run twice (and hence take 58 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you know how many times you want it to be executed

```
num_iter = 15
while [ num_iter > 0 ]
do
    sh script.sh
    sleep 2
    let "num_iter--"
done
```

Or use **watch -n** to repeat a command every n seconds. Then you wrap the watch function and kill it after specific amount of time

Comment: I don't know how many times I need it to be executed. I just know that I want to repeat the script *for*, say, 30 seconds.

Comment: I edited the script above to run for 30 seconds, as long as your script execution time doesn't take more than 2 seconds.